# How can I manually engage turbo on my processor when running Windows (Server 2008 R2) as a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, windows-server-2008-r2, turbo-boost

An application I run is heavily dependent upon raw processor speed as opposed to use of multiple cores.  The processors in my VM host have a base of 2.9 and can turbo up to 3.3, but it appears Windows has a conditional statement that says "if I am running in a virtual environment, disallow manual turbo control.

And to bring it back around, since my application doesn't focus on multiple cores, automatic trigger of turbo never happens since only one or two cores "see" heavy usage; from the processor's perspective it still has plenty of headroom and doesn't even need to think about turbo.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Turbo Boost**

On Intel CPUs Turbo only has two settings: "Auto" and "Off". In Auto mode, the processor itself decides whether to turbo if its internal rules decide there is enough headroom to do so. Turbo is basically always on "Auto" if enabled in the BIOS, until something switches it off.

Aside from overclocked processors, you cannot ever "manually engage turbo". The processor itself has complete and exclusive control over turbo modes and the OS cannot override it. All an OS can do is to tell the processor when *not* to turbo.

In normal operation your processor tells the OS what speeds it is capable of, and this list of speeds only goes up to the maximum non-turbo speed. The OS can request any speed from this list, or none at all. Your OS switches turbo off anytime it requests a speed from the processor that is below it's maximum non-turbo speed. Turbo is switched back to "Auto" anytime the OS requests the maximum speed from the given list.

**2. VM control**

Windows cannot control the speed of the host CPU from inside a VM. This is by design. The host OS should have its own CPU speed control system which autodetect the load and request lower CPU speeds when not needed. To allow the guest OS to control the host's CPU would involve passing through hardware control of the CPU (MSR) and this is not only a *major* security risk, it defeats the point of virtualisation in the first place.

**3. Multiple cores**

Your understanding seems to be the opposite of how turbo is intended to work. Turbo boost primarily increases speed *only* when one or two cores see heavy usage and is *least* effective when multiple cores are all loaded. The processor will *only* turbo when it has plenty of headroom.

Comment: Perhaps I should have phrased this more around c- and p-state control as the "manual control" aspect.  From a Linux perspective one can change the c-state of some cores to have them in sleep/deep sleep, resulting in headroom for the remaining cores to deliver into the turbo range (adjustment of p-state also at play).  So how about manual control of c- and p-state within Win Server 2008 R2 as a VM?  Oh, and yep, I agree that this means passthrough that is non-standard/less ideal for a VM setup - oh the things we do for the applications we work with ;)

Comment: @mpax: As stated, this is entirely controlled by the **host** OS and cannot be done by the VM. AFAIK, passthrough is simply not possible (not even using 'dirty hacks') I do not believe C-states are at all necessary for turbo-boost anymore, as the CPU uses it's internal TDP measurements now.